# Antispam Exchange Online Permission Error

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, spam-filter

We have Office 365 Accounts and also an Microsoft hostet Exchange online Server.
Normaly i could manage my antispam Rules and Policys in the **Exchange Admin Center**.
A few months ago there was the new Exchange Admin Center launched and the antispam Rules were moved to the **Microsoft 365 Defender** side, there i get an error for not having Permission.

[image: Microsoft 365 Defender Antispam]

I checked with multiple Admin Accounts, also created new accounts and assigned Exchange Admin rights, but still not working.
I created a ticket to microsoft, they check like 10 times and there is no error in their view. Does anyone else have similar Problems ?

Connected to Powerhsell i see all my antispam rules, they are active and i can create and edit existing ones. When i create a new rule on the Microsoft Defender side it shows in Powershell too.

Comment: Is there any updates on the issue?

Comment: Not yet, still waiting for an solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, comparing these information in the [blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/assign-portal-access?view=o365-worldwide) to check if the permissions have been assigned correctly.

Could you try change the browser to access the microsoft 365 defender? Or trying clear browser's cache and check again.

In addition, here's a troubleshooting step for your reference: [Troubleshoot subscription and portal access issues](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/troubleshoot-onboarding-error-messages?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: I check the permission twice with different accounts. No difference.
Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer all with same error, also tested with different Users on different Computers and Internet Connections. 

Troubleshootind didnt helped either.